# Large NTTPs (e.g. fixed strings) lead to issues: compile times, error messages

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

I'm using the following string class as NTTP.

```
struct fixed_string
{
    static constexpr size_t MaxSize = 16;

    constexpr fixed_string() = default;
    constexpr fixed_string( const std::string_view text ) : Size( text.size() < MaxSize ? text.size() : MaxSize )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < Size; ++i )
        {
            buffer[i] = text[i];
        }
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const { return Size; }
    constexpr auto get() const { return std::string_view( buffer, Size ); }

    size_t Size = 0;
    char buffer[MaxSize] = {};
};
```

In one case I use a 'composite NTTP', a (16x16) 2d array of these strings (wrapped in a class), making its size ~4 kilobytes.
The compiler (MSVC) does not seem to like this very much and compile times tank for a smallish tests project.

- What to do about it?
- How to get any insight into what is slowing the compiler down here?
- Is it even a good idea to use large NTTPs - error messages become a real pain
- Alternatives or better way to use them (e.g. wrapped/hashed)

Comment: Why not show the actual usage? This `fixed_string` class adds close to nothing to your question. You might as well have told us you use `std::array<char, 16>` as a NTTP.

Comment: Off topic note: you could use `std::copy` in `fixed_string`'s constructor instead of a raw loop. It's constexpr in C++20.

Comment: One idea: use a reference (in the normal, non-C++ sense of the term) in place of the composite NTTP, like some sort of ID number that represents it.

Comment: The rest of the code is work in progress and complex, the question was just trying to get insights into large NTTPs, if they are even a good idea, and how to better handle them. did some edits.

Comment: Even if the rest of the code is complex, you can try to build a [minimal (reproducible) example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from it. Reproducible may be hard to achieve since this is apparently about compiler performance, but a minimal example would give other people a starting point for investigation and it could even give you the insights you ask for, perhaps even ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Your symbol names are going to be huge.  And with 2^2^12 different NTTP, you could possibly have an insane number of compile time objects.  Compilers tend to memoize *everything* instantiated, and compile-time caching of state is often larger than the equivalent runtime.  How many of the 2^2^12 different NTTPs are being instantiated?  How often are the NTTP names being used to name classes?

Comment: So, you were trying to tell me that the compiler does not know better than to take the whole 4k as the symbol name? or worse?

Comment: @Nelfeal I don't quite see any benefit of std::copy - at compile time - one might even suspect it will be slower due to complexity

Comment: @non-user38741 Like I said, `std::copy` is constexpr in C++20, so it's not going to be any slower than a raw loop. I just prefer code that explicitly says what it does; plus, it's fewer lines of code.

Comment: *sigh*sigh*sigh*